# R Shiny DT - Searching a row whose name contains a '&' character doesn't yield any result

Tags: r, shiny, dt

In a DT object within a R Shiny app, when looking in the filter of the relevant column for a row whose name contains a character `&`, its name is found by the filter (selectize) but when selecting it, it doesn't appear as a result in the main table (I then get the error message: `No matching records found`).

I don't have a reprex as the table displayed is quite complex but I give below a very simplified reprex (that works) just to give an idea (the column `car_name` would be the column where a name contains a character `&`):

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

mydata <- head(mtcars, 30)
rownames(mydata)[which(rownames(mydata) == "Fiat X1-9")] <- "Fiat & X1-9"
mydata$car_name <- rownames(mydata)

ui <- fluidPage(
        mainPanel(
            datatable(mydata, rownames = FALSE, filter = 'top', options = list(order = list(list(2, 'asc'), list(4, 'desc'))))
        )
)
    
server <- function(input, output, session) {
}

runApp(list(ui = ui, server = server), launch.browser = TRUE)
```

Now the real options of my DT object are (in case it is possible to find where the issue comes from):

```
output$TableMassiveExport <- DT::renderDataTable({
        datatable(Generate_Table4ShinyDisplay(TableMassiveExport4ShinySelection, YE_Range_Augmented, 1:nrow(TableMassiveExport4ShinyDisplay)), rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, filter = 'top', selection = 'none', options = list(
        dom = 'tp',
        ordering = F,
        #searching = T,
        autoWidth = TRUE,
        columnDefs = list(list(targets = which(colnames(TableMassiveExport4ShinySelection) %in% YE_Range_Augmented) - 2 - 1, searchable = FALSE)),# -2 for the pseudonymised columns ("Undertaking.UltimateParent.Field4Search_Pseudo", "Undertaking.UltimateParent.Country_Pseudo")
        pageLength = 8,
        #lengthMenu = 1:10,
        #lengthMenu = c(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100),
        preDrawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.unbindAll(this.api().table().node()); }'),
        drawCallback = JS('function() { Shiny.bindAll(this.api().table().node()); } ')))
    }, server = TRUE)
    
TableMassiveExport_proxy <- DT::dataTableProxy("TableMassiveExport")
```

Comment: The question has been asked [here](https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/1075), but no reply.

Comment: It works for me. Did you upgrade **DT**?

Comment: Wow, you were quick, many thanks, @Stéphane Laurent!
It seems I was very lazy with my reprex...
When I ran the reprex on the Github page you mentioned in your first reply, I experienced exactly the same issue (that's a good reprex).
I'm using version 0.28 of DT, so the last one to date.
That's strange that it works for you...

Comment: Yihui Xie mentioned a few days ago on DT's GitHub that it should be fixed now.
https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/1075